# Is the preposition "with" correct in "...empty with the absence..."?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to ask if the preposition "with" is OK in this sentence:

> It was already 5:37, so the campus seemed empty with the absence of moving shadows and audible steps.

If it is not OK, what is the proper preposition? Or does the sentence need revision?

Comment: Preposition ***with*** is fine in your context. Note that in colloquial conversational contexts, many people would say it *seemed empty, **what with** the [absence of people]*. I can't explain why it feels somehow "better" to include ***what*** there informally even though I'm sure it wouldn't normally occur in more formal contexts. But I do have a bit of a problem with the *semantics* of ***already + so*** here, which implies *people who were recently around have disappeared because it's getting "late"*, whereas pragmatically I'd have thought *people aren't **yet** up and about.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

Answer (score -1):

The way you used "with" is clear and perfectly acceptable. I personally might use "and" instead of "so," but it really doesn't matter.

I'm not sure if it changes the meaning, but you could substitute the word "without" for "the absence of":

> ... the campus seemed empty without moving shadows and audible steps.

But there's no need to change anything because what you have is fine.

Comment: Hello, sw. Note that FF has already stated this. An 'answer' on ELU is far better if accompanied by supporting references / examples by respected authors.

Comment: But it's right, so there's really no need for supporting references or examples by respected authors. Right?